# Create one string with many user's input

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm working on a program that takes many inputs from the user,

and if he is writing `/end`, the program ends and prints one string with his inputs.
I have also added that if the user's string has started with a question word, it will automatically add a question mark to the string.

Now, my problem is that I don't know how can I put all the strings together, I have only tried with `append` but it is not working.

**Program:**

```
def stringCreator(mySTR):
    capitalized = mySTR.capitalize()
    questions = ('what', 'how', 'can', 'why')
    if mySTR.startswith(questions):
        return '{}?'.format(capitalized)
    else:
        return '{}.'.format(capitalized)


result = # What should I use there ?
while True:
    userInput = input('Say something: ')
    if userInput == '/end':
        break
    else:
        # Connect all string together with result


print(' '.join(stringCreator(result)))
```

**Edit:**

With **Wolph**'s help, I got this result.

First, I made a list with the `result`variable, second, I have added to the `else` condition `result.append(userInput)`,

and then I have changed the `print` function from

`print(' '.join(stringCreator(result)))` to `print(stringCreator(''.join(result)))`.

**Final Program:**

```
def stringCreator(mySTR):
    capitalized = mySTR.capitalize()
    questions = ('what', 'how', 'can', 'why')
    if mySTR.startswith(questions):
        return '{}?'.format(capitalized)
    else:
        return '{}.'.format(capitalized)


result = []
while True:
    userInput = input('Say something: ')
    if userInput == '/end':
        break
    else:
        result.append(userInput)


print(stringCreator(' '.join(result)))
```

Comment: Make `result` a list like so: `result = []` and you will be able to use `result.append(userInput)`. But you will need to reverse the `join()` operation: `print(stringCreator(' '.join(result)))`

Comment: @Wolph But list can't be `capitalized`, look at line 2

Comment: @Wolph No matter, it's now working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of options here. Probably the least efficient, but simplest, would be to append to the string directly:

```
result = ''
...
     result += userInput  # optionally + '\n'
```

A better way would be to append to a list and join later:

```
result = []
...
    result.append(userInput)
...
result = ' '.join(result)  # or '\n'
```

The best way would probably be to use a somewhat more specialised data structure, like [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to make appending much more efficient:

```
from collections import deque
...
result = deque()
...
```

The interface of `deque` is much like that of a list, but it can't do direct indexing very efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way :

```
def user_input():
    final=""
    input_str=""
    while(input_str!="/end"):
        final+=input_str+" "
        input_str=input("enter string and /end to stop : ")
    return final[1:]
print(user_input())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
enter string and /end to stop : hey
enter string and /end to stop : what
enter string and /end to stop : are
enter string and /end to stop : you
enter string and /end to stop : doing?
enter string and /end to stop : /end
hey what are you doing?
```